In javafx how to operate multiple tableview with single model?
Not my problem, just to be clear:
I am trying to develop an app which contains multiple tableview. Those tableviews are created in runtime on button click. I managed to do this task using tabpane and tab, and also managed to add different tableviews to those tab. By that users can create tables as per they want. Tabs are here closeable and create as much user want, on button click. One tab contain one tableview.
My problem:
So here i am dealing with too much tableviews with only one model. Those tableview contains textfield and buttons on there every columns and cells. It's also have the functionality to add and remove rows  from the tableview.
So here is my main problem, when user click button to add row in a specific tableview, this row automatically added in another tableview (which i doesn't want) which is in another tab. I does not wants to add row in a tableview when it is not selected or user is not wants to do the adding. Same case happens when its come to removing rows.
So, how can i add and remove rows on multiple tableview without any of those problem?
Here is the code i've been tried but failed. The purpose of giving a massive code block is to clear that i am on right path or not. If not please show the right path of doing this.
public static ObservableList<myModel> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

// in @override initialize method

tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Tab>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Tab> observableValue, Tab oldValue, Tab newValue) {
                System.out.println("Tab selected: " + newValue.getText());

                if (newValue.getContent() == null) {
                    System.out.println("New table created");
                    TableView<myModel> tableView = new TableView<>();
                    TableColumn<myModel, String> columnA = new TableColumn<>("A");
                    TableColumn<myModel, String> ColumnB = new TableColumn<>("B");
                    TableColumn<myModel, String> ColumnC = new TableColumn<>("C");
                    TableColumn<myModel, String> ColumnD = new TableColumn<>("D");
                    TableColumn<myModel, String> ColumnE = new TableColumn<>("E");
                    TableColumn<myModel, Button> ColumnF = new TableColumn<>("F");

                    Callback<TableColumn<myModel, Button>, TableCell<myModel, Button>> btncellFactory =
                            new Callback<TableColumn<myModel, Button>, TableCell<myModel, Button>>() {
                                @Override
                                public TableCell<myModel, Button> call(TableColumn<myModel, Button> elementsStringTableColumn) {
                                    final TableCell<myModel, Button> cell = new TableCell<myModel, Button>() {
                                        private final Button button = new Button("Delete");
                                        {
                                            button.setFocusTraversable(false);
                                            button.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                                                System.out.println("Deleting rows");
                                                TableRow row = this.getTableRow();
                                                row.updateSelected(true);
                                                System.out.println("row item: " + row.getItem() +" Index: "+ (row.getIndex()+1) + row.isSelected());
                                                getTableView().getItems().remove(row.getIndex()); //remove rows but not specific with tableviews thats why remove rows from all tableview
                                            });
                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        public void updateItem(Button item, boolean empty) {
                                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                            if (empty) {
                                                setGraphic(null);
                                            } else {
                                                setGraphic(button);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };

                                    return cell;
                                }
                            };

                    columnA.setCellFactory(ACellFactory.cell());
                    ColumnB.setCellFactory(BCellFactory.cell());
                    ColumnC.setCellFactory(CCellFactory.cell());
                    ColumnD.setCellFactory(DCellFactory.cell());
                    ColumnE.setCellFactory(ECellFactory.cell());
                    ColumnF.setCellFactory(btncellFactory);

                    addRowBtn.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                            list.add(new mymodel(myModel.getA(), myModel.getB(), myModel.getC(), myModel.getD(), myModel.getE()));  // on button click create a row
                        }
                    });

                    // I tried to do this to be specific on tableview which is on selected tab but failed
                    if (newValue.getText().equals(newValue.getText())) tableView.setItems(list);
                    tableView.getColumns().setAll(columnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE, ColumnF);
                    newValue.setContent(tableView);

                } else System.out.println("Containing table: " + newValue.getContent());

            }

        });                       
  

If anyone provide code of solving this problem please add comment about what your block of code actually do.

If you use the same list for all the tables, they will all contain the same data. If you want them to be independent, use a different list for each.

@James_D Can i create a different 'list' on runtime when user wants to add a table? Or what is the best solution for this problem? Please provide it would be very helpful.

Yes, of course. Just create a new list each time a new table is created, instead of reusing the same one. It’s not clear what the problem is. Create and post a [mre].

This example uses Pagination to display multiples views of the same model.


So here i am dealing with too much tableviews with only one model.

Assuming I understand your question correctly, the solution is just the obvious one: use a different model (i.e. a different ObservableList) for each table.
This will basically happen by default if you just set things up in the normal way, that is, just create a table view with add and remove buttons and a model for the table view, and add a new one to the tabbed pane each time you need.
Here is a simple example. First, a model class for the table items:
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Item {
    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public Item(String name) {
        setName(name);
    }
    public StringProperty nameProperty(){
        return name;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }
}

The FXML with the table view:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.tabbedtables.ItemTableController">

    <center>
        <TableView fx:id="table">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="nameCol"/>
            </columns>
        </TableView>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox spacing="5">
            <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="5"/></padding>
            <TextField fx:id="nameField" onAction="#addItem"/>
            <Button text="Add" onAction="#addItem"/>
            <Button fx:id="removeButton" text="Remove" onAction="#deleteSelected" />
        </HBox>
    </bottom>

</BorderPane>

and its controller, which here creates the items list (you can refactor this in any way you need, as long as you have a new list for each instance of the controller):

import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class ItemTableController {

    private final ObservableList<Item> itemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private Button removeButton;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Item> table;
    @FXML
    private TextField nameField;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        table.setItems(itemList);
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().nameProperty());
        removeButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
    }

    @FXML
    private void addItem() {
        Item item = new Item(nameField.getText());
        itemList.add(item);
        nameField.clear();
    }

    public void deleteSelected(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        itemList.remove(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    }
}

Here is the "main" view, with a tab pane and a button for adding new tabs (with the table in each tab):
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.tabbedtables.TabbedTablesController">
    <center>
        <TabPane fx:id="tabPane"/>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER">
            <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="10"/></padding>
            <Button text="New Table" onAction="#newTable"/>
        </HBox>
    </bottom>

</BorderPane>

and its controller, which loads the first FXML and adds it wrapped in a tab to the tab pane:
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TabbedTablesController {
    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;

    @FXML
    private void newTable() throws IOException {
        Tab tab = new Tab(STR."Table \{tabPane.getTabs().size() + 1}");
        tab.setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ItemTable.fxml")));
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);
        tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
    }
}

Finally, the application class:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TabbedTableApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(TabbedTableApp.class.getResource("TabbedTables.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

Since each controller for the table creates a different backing list, the data for the tables is independent. Here is a screenshot after adding two new tables, adding two items to the first and one to the second:


